# Using a set variable in a Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the following formula in a cell where Name is a defined cell. When I run 'MsgBox Name.Address' it gives me the correct cell, but when I run the formula I get

> run-time error '1004'

```
Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & Name.Address & ",EmployeeBank!C[-13]:C[-10],4,FALSE)"
```

The code also correctly places in the value of the variable if I remove .address

```
Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & Name & ",EmployeeBank!C[-13]:C[-10],4,FALSE)"
```

This gives me `=VLOOKUP(J Bob,EmployeeBank!A:D,4,FALSE)` in the cell. This would work but I can't put quotation marks around the name as these are already in place in the vba code. I tried doing multiple quotation marks and also `char(34)` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: For future reference, `Find` (with `Offset`) is a much better alternative in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an additional double quotation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, I was putting in the wrong number of quotation marks!!!!

```
Worksheets("EeeDetails").Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(""" & NewName & """,EmployeeBank!C[-13]:C[-10],4,FALSE)"
```